# Quad mesh generation code

Tags: graphics, mesh, numerical-methods, finite-element-analysis

I am looking for some sample code (any language) of quadrilateral mesh generation. However, is seems quite a difficult task!

I am not picky, I'd like to mesh at least polygons with holes, nothing fancy! So, we're talking about 2D planar shapes here.

Any hint?

PS. Of course, if it could even handle curved surfaces, I'd be even happier!

Comment: First hit in a google search for "quadrilateral mesh generation": http://www.robertschneiders.de/meshgeneration/software.html

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, however, I knew that too well! It's pretty outdated, and most of the libraries are for simplicial meshes: some quad libraries listed there are tri-quad converters...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quadrilateral meshing is by no means easy, especially if the elements should be more or less well-formed. There are no algorithms that can deal with any arbitrary shape without deteriorating element shapes. For a whole lot of problem classes, there are algorithms in applied mathematics and computational science books and papers.

Comment: I understand that... but my problem is, I think, easy: a simple polygon with holes. No fancy nurbs or even 3D shapes: just planar ones.

Comment: If the shapes are not too complicated, you could try with the obvious approach: Overlay a uniform grid, remove elements outside the domain and then move vertices outside the boundary of the domain onto the boundary. This should give you a quadrilateral mesh that shouldn't be too deformed. If necessary, you can still refine at the boundary.

Comment: I've resolved myself to implement a circle packing algorithm. Thanks for your pointers!